# VBA output in regards to option buttons

Tags: vba, excel, output, userform

I'm an A-Level student studying computer science and as part of my course I have to create a program. My program is VBA based and what it is meant to do is output details from userforms into my spreadsheet:

[Spreadsheet and the way it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amJYV.jpg)

I have created these 3 userforms:

```
imgur.com/ftqfEBt - Userform 1
imgur.com/pT2WHuD - Userform 2
imgur.com/BHHGOPv - Userform 3
```

What the program is meant to do is output all the details from the userforms into specific sections of the spreadsheet. The problem that I am getting is with userform 3 and the problem is that my code doesn't want to output into the spreadsheet. In order to explain what I mean I am going to put the code for all userforms below:

Userform 1

```
Private Sub Forename_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    'Set available characters to A-Z only
    If (KeyAscii < 65 Or KeyAscii > 90) And (KeyAscii < 97 Or KeyAscii > 122) Then KeyAscii = 0

End Sub

Private Sub Surname_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    'Set available characters to A-Z only
    If (KeyAscii < 65 Or KeyAscii > 90) And (KeyAscii < 97 Or KeyAscii > 122) Then KeyAscii = 0

End Sub

Private Sub School_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    'Set available characters to A-Z only
    If (KeyAscii < 65 Or KeyAscii > 90) And (KeyAscii < 97 Or KeyAscii > 122) Then KeyAscii = 0

End Sub

Private Sub Candidate_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
     'Set available characters to 0-9 only
    Select Case KeyAscii
        Case vbKey0 To vbKey9, vbKeyBack, vbKeyClear, vbKeyLeft, _
        vbKeyRight, vbKeyUp, vbKeyDown, vbKeyTab
    Case Else
        KeyAscii = 0
        Beep
    End Select

End Sub

Private Sub Closing_Click()
'Close the UserForm
Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub Reset_Click()
'Clear all fields
Call UserForm_Initialize

End Sub

Sub ValidtyCheck()

'Check if all data is entered correctly

If Forename.Value = "" Then
    Me.Forename.SetFocus
    MsgBox "The Forename is Missing"    'Validation Check - Makes sure the Value is not empty
End If

If Surname.Value = "" Then
    Me.Surname.SetFocus
    MsgBox "The Surnamee is Missing"    'Validation Check - Makes sure the Value is not empty
End If

If School.Value = "" Then
    Me.School.SetFocus
    MsgBox "The School you previously attended to is Missing"   'Validation Check - Makes sure the Value is not empty
End If

If Candidate.Value = "" Then
    Me.Candidate.SetFocus
    MsgBox "The Candidate number is Missing"    'Validation Check - Makes sure the Value is not empty
End If

If IsNumeric(Candidate.Value) = False Then
    MsgBox "Candidate number contains characters other than numbers"    'Validation Check - makes sure only numbers are entered
End If

If Trim(Me.Candidate.TextLength > 4) Then
    Me.Candidate.SetFocus
    MsgBox ("Candidate Number Contains more than 4 characters")   'Validation Check - Makes sure that no more than 4 characters are entered
End If

If Trim(Me.Candidate.TextLength < 4) Then
    Me.Candidate.SetFocus
    MsgBox ("Candidate Number Contains less than 4 characters")   'Validation Check - Makes sure that no less than 4 characters are entered
End If

End Sub

Sub Main()
    On Error GoTo NoBlanks
    Range("A1:A9000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = "N/A"

NoBlanks:
    Resume Next
    ' or add code here to execute when there are no empty cells
End Sub

Sub RemoveBlankRows()

'Deletes any row with blank cells located inside a designated range

On Error Resume Next

Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("A5:A9000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
rng.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub

Sub InputDetails()

'Input details into specific cells

Set ws = Sheets("Details")
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Forename.Value
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = Surname.Value
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Value = School.Value
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 4).Value = Candidate.Value

End Sub

Private Sub Submit_Click()

'Output all information into the spreadsheet

Call ValidtyCheck
Call RemoveBlankRows
Call InputDetails

Unload Me

'opens 2nd userform
GCSEsTaken.Show

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'Empty ForenameTextBox
Forename.Value = ""

'Clear SurnameTextBox
Surname.Value = ""

'Clear SchoolTextBox
School.Value = ""

'Clear CandidateTextBox
Candidate.Value = ""

'Set Focus on ForenameTextBox
Forename.SetFocus

End Sub
```

That is all the code for the whole of Userform 1. I know I am posting a lot of code but that's because I need to in order to show what is exactly wrong with it.

Userform 2

```
Private Sub Closing_Click()
'Close the UserForm
Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub Reset_Click()
'Clear all fields
Call UserForm_Initialize

End Sub

Private Sub GCSEsTaken_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
     'Set available characters to 0-9 only
    Select Case KeyAscii
        Case vbKey0 To vbKey9, vbKeyBack, vbKeyClear, vbKeyLeft, _
    vbKeyRight, vbKeyUp, vbKeyDown, vbKeyTab
    Case Else
        KeyAscii = 0
        Beep
    End Select

End Sub

Sub InputDetails()

'Input details into specific cells

Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 5).Value = GCSEsTaken.Value

End Sub

Private Sub Submit_Click()

Call InputDetails

Unload Me

'opens 2nd userform
GCSE.Show


End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Empty GCSE's Taken TextBox
GCSEsTaken.Value = ""

End Sub
```

The next piece of code is for Userform 3 and it is what is going wrong the stuff that are going wrong are within InputDetails() Sub. Plus if you have any idea I can shorten the OptionsValues () Sub then please do

```
Private Sub Closing_Click()
'Close the UserForm
Unload Me

End Sub



Private Sub Reset_Click()
'Clear all fields
Call UserForm_Initialize

End Sub

Private Sub OptionsValues()

MathsAx.Value = "A*"
MathsA.Value = "A"
MathsB.Value = "B"
MathsC.Value = "C"
MathsD.Value = "D"
MathsE.Value = "E"
MathsF.Value = "F"

EnglishLangAx.Value = "A*"
EnglishLangA.Value = "A"
EnglishLangB.Value = "B"
EnglishLangC.Value = "C"
EnglishLangD.Value = "D"
EnglishLangE.Value = "E"
EnglishLangF.Value = "F"
EnglishLangU.Value = "U"

EnglishLitAx.Value = "A*"
EnglishLitA.Value = "A"
EnglishLitB.Value = "B"
EnglishLitC.Value = "C"
EnglishLitD.Value = "D"
EnglishLitE.Value = "E"
EnglishLitF.Value = "F"
EnglishLitU.Value = "U"

SingSienceAx.Value = "A*"
SingSienceA.Value = "A"
SingSienceB.Value = "B"
SingSienceC.Value = "C"
SingSienceD.Value = "D"
SingSienceE.Value = "E"
SingSienceF.Value = "F"
SingSienceU.Value = "U"

DouScienceAx.Value = "A*"
DouScienceA.Value = "A"
DouScienceB.Value = "B"
DouScienceC.Value = "C"
DouScienceD.Value = "D"
DouScienceE.Value = "E"
DouScienceF.Value = "F"
DouScienceU.Value = "U"

TriScienceAx.Value = "A*"
TriScienceA.Value = "A"
TriScienceB.Value = "B"
TriScienceC.Value = "C"
TriScienceD.Value = "D"
TriScienceE.Value = "E"
TriScienceF.Value = "F"
TriScienceU.Value = "U"

REAx.Value = "A*"
REA.Value = "A"
REB.Value = "B"
REC.Value = "C"
RED.Value = "D"
REE.Value = "E"
REF.Value = "F"
REU.Value = "U"

ICTAx.Value = "A*"
ICTA.Value = "A"
ICTB.Value = "B"
ICTC.Value = "C"
ICTD.Value = "D"
ICTE.Value = "E"
ICTF.Value = "F"
ICTU.Value = "U"

DAndTAx.Value = "A*"
DAndTA.Value = "A"
DAndTB.Value = "B"
DAndTC.Value = "C"
DAndTD.Value = "D"
DAndTE.Value = "E"
DAndTF.Value = "F"
DAndTU.Value = "U"

HistoryAx.Value = "A*"
HistoryA.Value = "A"
HistoryB.Value = "B"
HistoryC.Value = "C"
HistoryD.Value = "D"
HistoryE.Value = "E"
HistoryF.Value = "F"
HistoryU.Value = "U"

GeographyAx.Value = "A*"
GeographyA.Value = "A"
GeographyB.Value = "B"
GeographyC.Value = "C"
GeographyD.Value = "D"
GeographyE.Value = "E"
GeographyF.Value = "F"
GeographyU.Value = "U"

MusicAx.Value = "A*"
MusicA.Value = "A"
MusicB.Value = "B"
MusicC.Value = "C"
MusicD.Value = "D"
MusicE.Value = "E"
MusicF.Value = "F"
MusicU.Value = "U"

DramaAx.Value = "A*"
DramaA.Value = "A"
DramaB.Value = "B"
DramaC.Value = "C"
DramaD.Value = "D"
DramaE.Value = "E"
DramaF.Value = "F"
DramaU.Value = "U"

SociologyAx.Value = "A*"
SociologyA.Value = "A"
SociologyB.Value = "B"
SociologyC.Value = "C"
SociologyD.Value = "D"
SociologyE.Value = "E"
SociologyF.Value = "F"
SociologyU.Value = "U"

PsychologyAx.Value = "A*"
PsychologyA.Value = "A"
PsychologyB.Value = "B"
PsychologyC.Value = "C"
PsychologyD.Value = "D"
PsychologyE.Value = "E"
PsychologyF.Value = "F"
PsychologyU.Value = "U"

EconomicsAx.Value = "A*"
EconomicsA.Value = "A"
EconomicsB.Value = "B"
EconomicsC.Value = "C"
EconomicsD.Value = "D"
EconomicsE.Value = "E"
EconomicsF.Value = "F"
EconomicsU.Value = "U"

FrenchAx.Value = "A*"
FrenchA.Value = "A"
FrenchB.Value = "B"
FrenchC.Value = "C"
FrenchD.Value = "D"
FrenchE.Value = "E"
FrenchF.Value = "F"
FrenchU.Value = "U"

SpanishAx.Value = "A*"
SpanishA.Value = "A"
SpanishB.Value = "B"
SpanishC.Value = "C"
SpanishD.Value = "D"
SpanishE.Value = "E"
SpanishF.Value = "F"
SpanishU.Value = "U"

ArabicAx.Value = "A*"
ArabicA.Value = "A"
ArabicB.Value = "B"
ArabicC.Value = "C"
ArabicD.Value = "D"
ArabicE.Value = "E"
ArabicF.Value = "F"
ArabicU.Value = "U"

PEAx.Value = "A*"
PEA.Value = "A"
PEB.Value = "B"
PEC.Value = "C"
PED.Value = "D"
PEE.Value = "E"
PEF.Value = "F"
PEU.Value = "U"


End Sub

Sub InputDetails()

'Input details into specific cells

If MathsAx.Value = True Then
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 6).Value = MathsAx.Value
'THIS IS JUST A CODE TEST HENCE WHY MOST QUOTED OUT I DON'T KNOW BUT IT DOESNT GIVE ANY VALUES IN THE SPREADHSEET
'Else
      '   Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = "No"
End If
'THIS CODE SEEMS TO WORK FOR THE PREVIOUS USERFORMS BUT THIS ONE IT DOESN'T WORK AT ALL AND I DON'T KNOW WHY
'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 6).Value = Frame1.Value
'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 7).Value = Frame2.Value
'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 8).Value = Frame3.Value
'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 9).Value = Frame4.Value
'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 10).Value = Frame5.Value
'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 11).Value = Frame6.Value
'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 12).Value = Frame7.Value
'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 13).Value = Frame8.Value
'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 14).Value = Frame9.Value
'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 15).Value = Frame10.Value
'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 16).Value = Frame11.Value
'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 17).Value = Frame12.Value
'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 18).Value = Frame13.Value
'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 19).Value = Frame14.Value
'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 20).Value = Frame15.Value
'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 21).Value = Frame16.Value
'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 22).Value = Frame17.Value
'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 23).Value = Frame18.Value
'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 24).Value = Frame19.Value
'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 25).Value = Frame20.Value

'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 26).Value = Other.Value


End Sub

Private Sub Submit_Click()

Call OptionsValues
Call InputDetails

Unload Me



End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()


'Empty Other TextBox
Other.Value = ""



 Dim ctlX As MSForms.Control

    For Each ctlX In Frame1.Controls
        If TypeOf ctlX Is MSForms.OptionButton Then
            If ctlX.Value Then
                ctlX.Value = False
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

I know I posted a lot of code but it's just that the code flows between each other and I don't understand why userform 3 doesn't give any details whatsoever.

Comment: Does InputDetails run at all? Have you tried using the VBA debugger? Or Debug.Print statements?

Comment: yes inputdetails does run its called upon when submit button is pressed. and no i havent used the debugger tbh i dont know how

Comment: I'd strongly suggest learning the debugger as your next course of action. Not only is it likely to get you an answer quicker, but it will also allow you to be more self-sufficient in the future. Here's one link to an explanation, but I'm sure there are a million others: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx

Comment: You should preface your code with Option Explicit and declare your variables. What is MathsAX? You assign it "A*" but then test it to be true. The string value won't evaluate to true, so the code in InputDetails won't do anything.

Comment: MathsAx is the name of the optionbutton so from OptionButton1 i renamed to MathsAx so its easier to know which is which and the x is there because it doesnt let you do an *. MathsAx is the option button for Maths A* in userform 3 on the picture. so what do you suggest in the if statemen i do something like this instead:

    If MathsAx.Value = True Then
         Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 6).Value = "A*"

Comment: @KarolKowalczyk - Well, I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish. If you merely want to check if MathsAx has a value, then do `If MathsAx.Value <> "" Then`. If you want to check that it has a number then `If IsNumeric(MathsAx.Value) Then`. The possibilities are large.

Comment: so what its meant to do is this. since there is 8 options which are A*,A,B,C,D,E,F,U right. its meant to get the answer from that one fram and put it in a designated space in the spreadhseet